# I try to put data in dataTable , but there is a mistake regarding the field of date

Tags: vb.net, datetime, dataset

I try to put data in dataTable by this code

```
    ds.Tables.Add("main")

    ds.Tables("main").Columns.Add("BRANCH", GetType(Integer))
    ds.Tables("main").Columns.Add("TAXEN_DATE", GetType(Date))

    ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add()
    ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) = 1
    ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1) = "23/12/1979"
```

but there is a mistake regarding the field of date , the system works on some devices, but some give me this message

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <23/12/1979> in TAXEN_DATE Column.  Expected type is DateTime.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euZoM.png)

I searched for a solution, but I could not find a suitable solution.

Comment: `"23/12/1979"` is a string, not a date.  If it wont convert on some systems, it is likely because it is not a valid format in that culture

Comment: That's right, how to fix it ?

Comment: The answer is obvious: create a DatTime variable rather than passing a string.  Strings are not DateTime types.  Read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Thanks for everything, and found the solution #23/12/1979#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast you string `23/12/1979` to a `DateTime` format.

**Your Code fixed**

```
ds.Tables.Add("main")

ds.Tables("main").Columns.Add("BRANCH", GetType(Integer))
ds.Tables("main").Columns.Add("TAXEN_DATE", GetType(Date))

ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add()
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) = 1
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1) = Convert.ToDateTime("23/12/1979")
```